# How to compare installed app versionCode to current versionCode(new)?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I want to give notification to user that he can upgrade app version. for that I need to compare installed app versionCode to current versionCode.

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionCode;
```

- Q1. which version I get in `version`, installed or current(new) ?
- Q2. If `version` have current than how I can get installed ?
- Q3. If `version` have installed than how I can get current ?

Comment: But I think you should be using the version name and not the version code(Just a suggestion)

Comment: What is the difference between using versionCode and versionName ? Why it is a better Idea ?

Comment: Check your manifest.. Version code is actually the build version. The version name corresponds to the version of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you a way to do it.

- There is a version code in your manifest file. Suppose in your first release you set it to 1.
- In you launch code keep that value in a sharedPreference.
- Not keep a text file in some server (may be you can use app spot for this purpose). In this file keep a field as versioncode.
- Everytime you give a update, increment the version code in this file as you do in manifest file
- Everytime on app launch, you can read the the file from server, do json parsing and get the version code.
- Then compare this value with your sharedFreference version code. If same, that means no update. If new versioncode is higher, then pop a dialog with your google play link. Also update your sharedPreference.
- You can check for version code value every 3 days may be in app launch rather than checkin it each time as it requires little data download and some processing.

I use this way and it works for me..

Do let me know if any further clarification is required.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this may be help you**

```
public void printDeviceConfig(Context context) {


        try {
            System.err.println("=============== HEAP INFO ===============================");

            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
            activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
            System.err.println("Over All Memory: " + (memoryInfo.availMem / 1024) + " KB");
            System.err.println("low Memory: " + memoryInfo.lowMemory);
            System.err.println("Threshold Memory: " + (memoryInfo.threshold / 1024) + " KB");

            System.err.println("=============== OS INFO ===============================");
            System.err.println("Device MODEL: " + android.os.Build.MODEL);
            System.err.println("VERSION RELEASE: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
            System.err.println("VERSION SDK: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

            System.err.println("=============== Device Information ===============================");
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            System.err.println("Device Resolution (WxH)= " + dm.widthPixels + " x " + dm.heightPixels);

            System.err.println("Density DPI= " + dm.densityDpi);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
        }


    }
```